# Is there any method that i can continue on the next line after getting exceptions in Java?

Tags: java, exception

I have a problem in java, as we know if there is some code error due to some exceptions, our code will not able to run if we are not setting up try-catch block, but sometimes, we don't know which line make problem, for example, this one

```
    @Test
    public void testExceptions(int a , int b) {
        GlobalExceptionHandler globalExceptionHandler = new GlobalExceptionHandler();
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(globalExceptionHandler);
        System.out.println("Error ");
        Integer c = a + b;
        Integer d = a * b;
        Integer e = a / b;
        Integer f = a - b;
        Integer g = f / c;
        Integer h = g * c;
        System.out.println("this is new Line");
    }
```

I want to know all results `c, d, e, f, g, and h` but as you know variables `e` and `g` might have possibility get an error because divided by 0, and the program will exit at that time `( in e or g )`

is there any way for running the rest of the code, when we execute variable e and get errors without exiting the program immediately and without writing `try-catch` blocks?

Thank you

Comment: No, there is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test for user input(?) 
add an if statement before the '/' operators.

also, try-catch is there EXACTLY for, well, catching this sort of errors.
If you can specify why you cant use them, 
perhaps it will help find a way around the issue.
(its like saying you need "a whole number" but cannot use "integer")

Tl;dr -> just add an (b!=0) "if" statement before your "e=a/b"